# Node.js - Body is messed up when using json.stringify

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express

Client:

```
$.ajax({
  url: some_url,
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify({myArray: []})
  ...
}

$.ajax({
  url: some_url,
  type: 'post',
  data: {myArray: []}
  ...
}
```

Server:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser()); // body-parser module
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.body);

  // When stringified, prints: { '{"myArray":': { ']': '' } }
  // When not stringified, prints: {}

});
```

I understand that because my array is empty, it is not posted, but I am completely confused as to why the output is so messed up when stringified. Is it caused by the body parser?

All I want to do is retrieve my array and loop on it. If it's empty, so be it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `dataType` only affects the server *response*. It has nothing to do with the request data.

Secondly, the reason for the mangled object is that by default jQuery's `ajax()` sends a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Also the `body-parser` middleware will by default use the `qs` npm module to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of the built-in `querystring` node module. The `qs` module supports features above and beyond that of `querystring`, including nested syntax (e.g. `foo[bar]=baz` and `foo[]=baz`). So `qs` sees the `[` and thinks it's the beginning of nested syntax. From there it depends on `qs`'s implementation as to what the output looks like for the malformed input.

Answer (score 3):

The `bodyParser()` middleware decodes based on the request's `Content-Type` header, which can be set with the [`contentType` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
data: JSON.stringify({ myArray: [] }),
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Without specifying that the `contentType` is JSON, the parser will attempt to decode based on the default of URL-encoding, resulting in the `body` structure you see.

Comment: I accepted mscdex's answer because it explained why the body was so messed up, but your answer is just as good and I would've accepted both if I could.